# How do you replace pandas row numeric values with string?

Tags: pandas, replace, rename, rows

I cannot solve this problem after trying to rename row values "13.0" with "west" in the following dataframe df1 below:

```
      site  Max SurfPres N-S Gradient  Max SurfPres W-E Gradient
Year                                                            
1992  13.0                   1.079362                  -0.857944
1993  13.0                   0.480637                  -0.876781
1994  13.0                   0.031870                   0.389390
```

I've tried,

```
df1['site'] = df1['site'].replace(['13.0'],'west')
```

and,

```
df1['site'].replace(['13.0'],['west'],inplace=True)
```

Both of these attempts below do nothing - with the row value of '13.0' failing to be replaced with 'west'. Thank you,

Comment: maybe there are numeric values? `df1['site'] = df1['site'].replace(13.0,'west')` ?

Answer (score 1):

Seems values are numeric:

```
df1['site'] = df1['site'].replace(13.0,'west')
```

Or convert column to strings first:

```
df1['site'] = df1['site'].astype(str).replace('13.0','west')
```